# python join string without linebreak from a master file

Tags: python

I have a master file with fruits

Example:

```
"banana"

"grape"

"watermelon"

"melon"
```

and what to save then I different files with a template

I'm using this code:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
   k=open('output folder\\'+line+'.txt', 'w')
   k.write('a'+line+'b')'
```

but instead of getting a file banana.txt with text `abananab`

I get an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'output\\"banana"\n.txt'
```

because the code create a line break `\n`

How I can fix this?

Comment: `line.strip()` maybe?  You might also want to `.strip` the quotes as well...

Answer (score 0):

Change the file open statement:

```
open('output\ folder\\'+line.strip()[1:-1]+'.txt', 'w')
```

or just use strip:

```
open('output\ folder\\'+line.strip('"\n')+'.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Or just do `line.strip('\n"')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
`for line in f:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    ...`

`for line in f:
    line = line[:-1]
    ...`

`for line in f.readlines():
    ...`

`for line in list(f):
     ...`
```

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the return value unambiguous; if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by '\n', a string containing only a single newline.

you nead readlines() -> note the 's' in readlines